# Draw a complex circle (Has border only on the left half of it) using Android Shapes

Tags: android, geometry, shapes, oval

I'm trying to draw a complex circle with the right half different from the second one using the XML description of Android.

The final circle should have border on the left and no border on the right.

I though about creating two different circles (One with border, the other without) and merge them but I did not manage to do it.
Any ideas?

**first_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
</shape>
```

**second_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    <stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="@color/lectra_black" />
</shape>
```

**final_circle.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:drawable="@drawable/first_circle">
    </item>
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:drawable="@drawable/second_circle">
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: showing some code would be better

Comment: First time posting on stackoverflow, sorry, I'm updating my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my question : half circle with counter, the other half without.

**drawable** contains circle_grey.xml, counter_black.xml, counter_black_clip.xml.

**layout** contains activity_main.xml.

**circle_grey.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#A0A0A0"/>
</shape>
```

**counter_black.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="oval" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="80sp" android:height="80dp" />
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

**counter_black_clip.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/counter_black"
    android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_grey"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layout_half_cercle"
            android:weightSum="7"
            android:background="@drawable/counter_black_clip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.java**

```
package app.test.com.myapplication;

import android.graphics.drawable.ClipDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout layoutDate = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_half_cercle);
        ClipDrawable drawable = (ClipDrawable) layoutDate.getBackground();
        drawable.setLevel(drawable.getLevel() + 5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. This is the best example of how to simply implement a ClipDrawable - using 2 shapes (drawable resources) to create a new one using  for those using it for purposes other than for a progress bar.